# ADF Mobile Exception when adding contact

Tags: java, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

When I try to add contacts with ADF Mobile, I get this Exception:

> ERROR CODE:0

My Code:

```
Contact newcontact = device.createContact(contact);
```

What's the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only line of code you write to create contact, then it won't work like that, please review https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfE0Xg0eSqY

if you did all the requirements to create contact and populated all required field before executing this line then please share full code in order to be able to help you.

Comment: it work fine, but when i add a compte(exchange for example) , this exception apear. i guess the contacts are lucked by others applications. anyone have a solution?